How is Gaussian log likelihood value calculated in weighted LM, GLM and GLS?
I have examined these R functions glm.fit() gaussian()$aic stats:::logLik.glm() and stats:::logLik.lm() and found that the log likelihood value reported by stats:::logLik.glm() is calculated based on gaussian()$aic which is defined as
function (y, n, mu, wt, dev) 
{
  nobs <- length(y)
  nobs * (log(dev/nobs * 2 * pi) + 1) + 2 - sum(log(wt))
}

The log likelihood value reported by stats:::logLik.lm() is calculated using the following formula.
0.5 * (sum(log(w)) - N * (log(2 * pi) + 1 - log(N) + 
    log(sum(w * res^2))))

These two formulae lead to identical logLik and AIC in the Gaussian family. I wonder why they should be calculated in the above way. Using sum of log density values based on the classical formula as shown in "Normal distribution - Maximum Likelihood Estimation" https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/normal-distribution-maximum-likelihood, I arrived at different log likelihood values and cannot recognize the relationship between my calculation and the default outputs. See the following minimal example.
library(nlme)
Data <- data.frame(
  y = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.3), 
  n = c(10, 20, 30)
)
with(Data, sum(y * n)/sum(n)) # 0.25

# GLM model
summary(Model <- glm(y ~ 1, weights = n, data = Data))
"            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.25000    0.03536   7.071   0.0194 *
(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.075)
    Null deviance: 0.15  on 2  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 0.15  on 2  degrees of freedom
AIC: -5.1731"
sigma(Model)
"0.2738613"
with(Model, prior.weights)
" 1  2  3 
10 20 30 "
with(Model, weights)
" 1  2  3 
10 20 30 identical, no iterative reweighting"
logLik(Model)
"4.58654 (df=2)"
AIC(Model)
"-5.17308 because -2 * 4.58654 + 2 * 2 == -5.17308"
with( # Based on gaussian()$aic and glm.fit()
  Model, nobs(Model) * (log(deviance/nobs(Model) * 2 * pi) + 1) + 
    2 - sum(log(weights)))
"-7.17308
-7.17308 + 2*1 == -5.17308 is the reported AIC
logLik is derived from the AIC measure"

# OLS model
summary(Model <- lm(y ~ 1, weights = n, data = Data, x = TRUE, y = TRUE))
"            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.25000    0.03536   7.071   0.0194 *
Residual standard error: 0.2739 on 2 degrees of freedom
identical results as glm()"
sigma(Model)
"0.2738613, same as glm()"
with(Model, sigma(Model)^2)
"sum(weights * residuals^2) weighted RSS 0.15
sum(weights * residuals^2)/df.residual 0.075 is sigma^2
sigma(Model)^2 = 0.075"
logLik(Model)
"4.58654 (df=2) identical as above"
logLik(Model, REML = TRUE)
"2.054975 (df=2)"
AIC(Model)
"-5.17308 identical as above"
with(Model, 0.5 * (
  sum(log(weights)) - nobs(Model) * (
    log(2 * pi) + 1 - log(nobs(Model)) + log(sum(weights * residuals^2)))))
"4.58654 is the reported logLik"
with(Model, sum(weights * log(
  dnorm(y, mean = coef(Model), sd = sigma(Model)))))
"21.5717 does not match logLik"

# GLS model
summary(Model <- gls(y ~ 1, weights = ~ 1/n, data = Data, method = "ML"))
"       AIC       BIC  logLik
  -5.17308 -6.975856 4.58654  These match OLS and GLM results
Variance function:
 Structure: fixed weights
 Formula: ~1/n 
Coefficients:
            Value  Std.Error  t-value p-value
(Intercept)  0.25 0.03535534 7.071068  0.0194
Residual standard error: 0.2236068

0.2236068 = 0.2738613 * sqrt(2/3) is underestimated resid SE"

# Manual calculation
# Based on log(L) = sum w * log(f)
summary(Model <- glm(y ~ 1, weights = n, data = Data))
with(Model, sum(prior.weights * log(
  dnorm(y, mean = coef(Model), sd = sigma(Model)))))
"21.5717"
with(Model, sum(weights) * (-1/2 * log(2 * pi)))
"-55.13631"
with(Model, sum(weights) * (-1/2 * log(sigma(Model)^2)))
"77.70801"
with(Model, (-1/(2 * sigma(Model)^2)) * sum(weights * (y - coef(Model))^2))
"-1
-55.13631 + 77.70801 - 1 == 21.5717
Does not match logLik() results"

Partial Answer
The regular Gaussian density function is
$f_a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp{-\frac{(y_i − \hat{y}_i)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$
but when there are weights, it becomes
$f_b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2/w_i}}\exp{-\frac{(y_i − \hat{y}_i)^2}{2\sigma^2/w_i}}$
which says that the underlying normal distribution has a variance of $\sigma^2/w_i$. Intuitively, it is analogous to the mean standard error calculated as $SD/\sqrt{n}$, which indicates that a larger group size (i.e., weight) leads to smaller error variance $s^2/n$. The previous calculation mistakenly uses $f_b = (f_a)^{w_i}$, which should be applied to discrete data. See the manual calculation below that reproduces logLik() results.
# Manual calculation
# Based on using sigma^2/weights in each log(f)
summary(Model <- glm(y ~ 1, weights = n, data = Data))
with(Model, sum(log(dnorm(
  y, mean = fitted(Model), sd = sigma(Model)/sqrt(prior.weights)))))
"4.478343"
with(Model, -nobs(Model)/2*(
  log(2*pi) + log(sum(weights * residuals^2)) - log(df.residual)) +
    sum(log(weights))/2 - df.residual/2)
"4.478343"
with(Model, sum(log(dnorm(
  y, mean = fitted(Model), sd = sigma(Model) * 
    sqrt((nobs(Model) - 1)/nobs(Model)) /sqrt(prior.weights)))))
"4.58654 equals logLik()"
with(Model, -nobs(Model)/2*(
  log(2*pi) + log(sum(weights * residuals^2)) - log(nobs(Model))) +
    sum(log(weights))/2 - nobs(Model)/2)
"4.58654 equals logLik()"

Both stats:::logLik.lm() and stats:::logLik.glm() based on gaussian()$aic use $N\sigma^2 = \sum{w_i(y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2}$ to cancel the term of $\sigma$ above. However, I do not understand why $(N-p)\sigma^2 = \sum{w_i(y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2}$ is not used by default, where $N - p$ is the residual degree of freedom and $p$ is the number of coefficients to estimate including the intercept (i.e., rank of the design matrix). It is how $\sigma$ is derived in both lm() and glm(), corresponding to an unbiased estimate of the residual variance instead of the maximum likelihood estimator in gls() that underestimates the residual variance. The underestimated residual variance is used in calculating log likelihood by logLik() even for unweighted OLS models, as demonstrated below.
# No weights
with(Data, mean(y))
"0.2333333"

# LM/GLM without weights
summary(Model <- glm(y ~ 1, data = Data))
"            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.23333    0.03333       7   0.0198 *
(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.003333333)
    Null deviance: 0.0066667  on 2  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 0.0066667  on 2  degrees of freedom
AIC: -5.8141"
sigma(Model)
"0.05773503"
logLik(Model)
"4.907056 (df=2)"
logLik(lm(y ~ 1, data = Data))
"Identical to above"
AIC(Model)
"-5.814112 because -2 * 4.907056 + 2 * 2 == -5.814112"
Model$weights
"1 2 3 
1 1 1 weights used in iterative reweighting"
Model$prior.weights
"1 2 3 
1 1 1 weights of observations"
with(Model, sum(log(dnorm(
  y, mean = fitted(Model), sd = sigma(Model)))))
"4.798858 does not match logLik(Model)"
with(Model, -nobs(Model)/2*(
  log(2*pi) + log(sum(weights * residuals^2)) - log(df.residual)) +
    sum(log(weights))/2 - df.residual/2)
"4.798858 same as above"
with(Model, sum(log(dnorm(
  y, mean = fitted(Model), sd = sigma(Model) * 
    sqrt((nobs(Model) - 1)/nobs(Model))))))
"4.907056 matches logLik(Model)"
with(Model, -nobs(Model)/2*(
  log(2*pi) + log(sum(weights * residuals^2)) - log(nobs(Model))) +
    sum(log(weights))/2 - nobs(Model)/2)
"4.907056"

# GLS without weights
summary(Model <- gls(y ~ 1, data = Data))
"         AIC       BIC   logLik  These are REML measures
  -0.6331985 -3.246904 2.316599
                Value  Std.Error t-value p-value
(Intercept) 0.2333333 0.03333333       7  0.0198
Residual standard error: 0.05773503 
Degrees of freedom: 3 total; 2 residual
Default fitting method is REML, 0.05773503 matches sigma(Model) of lm glm"
summary(Model <- gls(y ~ 1, data = Data, method = "ML"))
"        AIC       BIC   logLik
  -5.814112 -7.616887 4.907056
                Value  Std.Error t-value p-value
(Intercept) 0.2333333 0.03333333       7  0.0198
Residual standard error: 0.04714045 
Degrees of freedom: 3 total; 2 residual
0.04714045 = 0.05773503 * sqrt(2/3) is underestiated residual SE"
logLik(Model)
"4.907056 (df=2) matches lm() and glm()"
with(Model, sum(log(dnorm(
  fitted + residuals, mean = fitted, sd = sigma(Model)))))
"4.907056 matches above"

Remaining Question
Should the log likelihood value of OLS models be based on not the unbiased residual variance relationship $\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum{w_i(y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2}}{N - p}$ that lm() and glm() use but the underestimated residual variance relationship $\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum{w_i(y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2}}{N}$ used in gls()? Or does the logLik() function in R have mistakes in this part for lm() and glm() models? See the following for a short and simple comparison.
# Simple comparison
Data <- data.frame(y = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.3))
logLik(Model <- lm(y ~ 1, data = Data))
logLik(Model <- glm(y ~ 1, data = Data))
with(Model, sum(log(dnorm(
  y, mean = fitted(Model), sd = sigma(Model)))))
"4.798858 does not match logLik(Model)"
with(Model, sum(log(dnorm(
  y, mean = fitted(Model), sd = sigma(Model) * 
    sqrt((nobs(Model) - 1)/nobs(Model))))))
"4.907056 matches logLik(Model)"
logLik(Model <- gls(y ~ 1, data = Data, method = "ML"))
"Same as above"

I understand that $AIC = -2 \ln{L} + 2df$ where $df$ is the number of parameters in the fitted model, but why stats:::logLik.lm() and stats:::logLik.glm() for family %in% c("gaussian", "Gamma", "inverse.gaussian") use $df = p + 1 = 2$ in the above intercept-only models? Is it because we should treat both the intercept and the residual variance/SE as two separate parameters, although only the former is estimated directly?

You're asking us to debug your code--that's for [SO], not here.  But if you would care to explain what you think your code is doing, we might be able to comment on that.

It was not about debugging the code. I want to understand what formula standard software uses to calculate the Gaussian log likelihood, which does not match the typical definition. So I think it is purely a statistical question. I supplied scripts instead of equations to make the calculation more transparent.

"What formulas ... software uses" sounds explicitly like a programming question, doesn't it?

Shouldn't the formulas say $(y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2$, ie. with the square outside of the brackets.

@dipetkov noted. I just updated my question with correct formulae and additional examples.

TLDR, I can't easily see what you are exactly asking. Could you simplify your question to a single case/comparison and your code could be a comparison of just two lines of code.

@SextusEmpiricus, I resolved some parts of my question. My remaining part of question and a short example are listed at the bottom in "New Questions" now.

@DrJerryTAO it is still a very long unfocused question with a lot of code. Can't you pose the question in something like 250 words and provide a simpler/shorter code to explain the isssue.

The “Remaining Question” section has no more than 20 words and six lines of code.

@DrJerryTAO it is very confusing to have such a long question. So basically your question is whether the maximum likelihood estimate should use $N$ or $N-p$ in the estimate of $\sigma$?

Yes. I found lm and glm use $N - p$ to estimate $\sigma$, but their logLik methods use $N$ in substitution for $\sigma^2$, which is weird to me. Gls uses $N$ for both residual SE and logLik purposes, which is at least a consistent usage.

The likelihood value may depend on the method of estimation and you may get differences with a manual computation when you do not apply the same estimate. The difference between the use of $N$ or $N-p$ in the denominator is one such example.
A related question with such a discrepancy is Likelihood from forecast::Arima vs. manual replication where the manual computation used the corrected standard deviation which is output from the forecast::Arima function. But that is a wrapper function and it is not the estimate used in the computation of the likelihood which is done by the underlying stats::arima function.

Whatever case you use, the effect of using $n-p$ or $n$ in the denominator only changes the log likelihood function by a constant. And for likelihood ratios it doesn't matter.
The log likelihood as function of $\sigma$ is :
$$\log \mathcal{L}(\sigma) = -0.5 n \log(2\pi) -n \log(\sigma) - \frac{RSS}{2\sigma^2}$$
with the residual sum of squares $RSS = \sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{y}_i -y_i)^2$
We could use an estimate $\hat\sigma^2 = \frac{RSS}{d}$ and you get
$$\log \mathcal{L}(\hat\sigma) = \text{constant} - n\log(RSS)$$
with $$\text{constant} = -0.5 n \log(2\pi) + 0.5 n \log(d)- 0.5 d $$
and wheter we use denominators $d=n$ or $d=n-p$, it only changes the log likelihood function by a change in the constant.

For the same model estimated by lm and glm, sigma() uses $N - p$ to estimate the residual standard error, whereas logLik uses $N$ when substituting for $\sigma^2$. Do you have explanation why the degree of freedom choices are different for these two purposes?

@DrJerryTAO It can be that the choices diverge for functions sigma() and logLik. They are arbitrary choices. For the individual cases it makes sense to 1) use the likelihood evaluated for the maximum likelihood estimate 2) report bias corrected estimates for $\sigma$.

There is actually a little influence on the likelihood due to the constant. This happens when we compare models with different number of parameters. If the used denominator in the estimate of $\hat{\sigma}$ is $d=n-p$ then the "constant" is not constant and instead changes for different models.

Relating to the previous comment. If $n$ is large then $$n\log(n-p) \approx n \log n - p  $$ and $$0.5n\log(n-p) - 0.5(n-p) \approx 0.5n\log n - 0.5 n$$ and in the limit of large $n$ the AIC is not influenced by the method of estimating $\hat{\sigma}$.
